# Can an interface object be used directly?

Tags: java, android, interface

While using the Google Places API, I came across this piece of code:

```
Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
```

This works fine. However, on exploration, I came across something which I didn't understand. **Place** is an interface, which has only getter methods. The following is code for interface Place:

```
public interface Place extends Freezable<Place> {
    int TYPE_OTHER = 0;
    /* ... Similar type declarations */
    int TYPE_SYNTHETIC_GEOCODE = 1029;
    int TYPE_TRANSIT_STATION = 1030;

    String getId();

    List<Integer> getPlaceTypes();

    CharSequence getAddress();

    Locale getLocale();

    CharSequence getName();

    LatLng getLatLng();

    LatLngBounds getViewport();

    Uri getWebsiteUri();

    CharSequence getPhoneNumber();

    float getRating();

    int getPriceLevel();

    CharSequence getAttributions();
}
```

The code for PlacePicker.getPlace() is as follows:

```
public class PlacePicker extends zza {
    public static final int RESULT_ERROR = 2;

    private PlacePicker() {
    }

    public static Place getPlace(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return zza.getPlace(context, intent);
    }

    /* Rest code of the class */
}
```

Here the signature of the class **zza** is `protected abstract static class zza`.

EDIT: 
The code of class **zza**

```
abstract class zza {
    public static final int RESULT_ERROR = 2;

    zza() {
    }

    public static Place getPlace(Context context, Intent intent) {
        zzx.zzb(intent, "intent must not be null");
        zzx.zzb(context, "context must not be null");
        return (Place)zzc.zza(intent, "selected_place", PlaceImpl.CREATOR);
    }

    public static Status getStatus(Context context, Intent intent) {
        zzx.zzb(intent, "intent must not be null");
        zzx.zzb(context, "context must not be null");
        return (Status)zzc.zza(intent, "status", Status.CREATOR);
    }

    protected abstract static class zza {
        protected final Intent mIntent;

        public zza(String var1) {
            this.mIntent = new Intent(var1);
            this.mIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gms");
        }

        protected Intent build(Activity activity) throws GooglePlayServicesRepairableException, GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException {
            Theme var2 = activity.getTheme();
            TypedValue var3 = new TypedValue();
            TypedValue var4 = new TypedValue();
            if(var2.resolveAttribute(16843827, var3, true) && !this.mIntent.hasExtra("primary_color")) {
                this.mIntent.putExtra("primary_color", var3.data);
            }

            if(var2.resolveAttribute(16843828, var4, true) && !this.mIntent.hasExtra("primary_color_dark")) {
                this.mIntent.putExtra("primary_color_dark", var4.data);
            }

            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().zzak(activity);
            return this.mIntent;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is that, when none of the classes have implemented `Place` interface, how does `place.getName()` work? Where exactly is the method definition written?

Comment: Now look at the code for `zza.getPlace`. Some class *has* implemented these methods; otherwise it would not be possible to instantiate it.

Comment: I checked, I didn't find anything there. I'll add that class also here. You have exactly stated what I believe. Some class has to implement. I fail to find it however. This has left me baffled!

Comment: The Point is: the authors of `zza` don't want you to know about the implementation details of `Place` so this is hidden as best as possible. Anyhow, it seems that some components can store a `Place` object in the `context` memory. `zza` is just a utility, that can extract it.

Comment: @SME_Dev I have added the zza class too. Is it that they pass it via Intents? I can't get a direct hold of the class that's implementing it.

Comment: @ObscureGeek Yes thats very possible, since `Intent` can e.g. contain any `Serializable` or `Parceable` object and they can be sent by any installed android broadcasting service or application.

Comment: @SME_Dev I found out. The `PlaceImpl` class implements `Place`. Thanks for your help!